# Should I perform a Post Hoc analysis if I get no significant interaction in two way anova?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, interaction, two-way

[image]

[image]
Hello all!

I am performing a two-way ANOVA for an experiment I am doing but I reached a concern. I saw no significant interaction effect, still, I performed a post hoc TUKEY test and got significance between some specific treatments. Is this appropriate to do?

I added the Tukey test. I would like to know if it is correct to mention both significant difference found in the test such as:

OA:AB - DMSO:AB
DMSO:SCR - OA:AB

Help!

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you found with the Tukey test. You don't need to have a significant interaction term to do such a test. Clearly the value of predictor `A` matters a lot.

Comment: Thank you! I already did it! Let me know what do you think!

Comment: It's still hard to interpret the question, as it's not clear how `OA`, `DMSO`, `SCR` and `AB` correspond to the `A`, `B` and `A:B` terms in the ANOVA report. Please further edit the question to explain that and to show the actual commands you performed both for ANOVA and the Tukey test. Also, please replace the images of output; paste in the corresponding text and format as code instead. Select the text you want to format as code and press the "{}" tool on the editing toolbar. (That shifts all those lines in by 4 spaces, which is interpreted by the browser as formatted code.)